# What's the difference between virtualenv and using pip install with --ignore-installed and --user options?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, dependencies, virtualenv

I was going through the documentation of pip, and also looking at virtualenv. If we set the `PYTHONUSERBASE` variable, and run `pip install` with the `--ignore-installed` and `--user` options , we are basically telling pip to download the packages in the local folder ignoring everything that's present in the global site-packages path. As per my understanding, virtualenv is used to accomplish a similar goal. Then why should I use virtualenv? Is there any added benefit, if we're only dealing with a single python installation on our machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that a user can have many virtual environments, every one with different versions of packages and their dependencies. With `pip install --user` a user can only have one version of a package.

Comment: Thanks phd. That makes sense. However, if I change the pythonuserbase variable before running `pip install --user`, I can get the same end result, but it'd be tedious since you have to create multiple directories before running the project, something implicitly done by virtualenv. I get the difference, it seems intuitive now after reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv makes a separate copy of python installation and the site packages. Suppose we write a code today and its working perfectly. But a month later, we have updated a package (eg numpy) for some reason. Now its possible that the code that was working last month might not work today because of the update. So, to avoid this we use virtualenv.

Note: I am an amateur computer programmer and don't know much about the technical stuff. Just sharing what I know.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Manideep. I understand the use of virtualenv, and the use case you specified can be accomplished with the pip install --user option as well. However, as the other answer says, virtualenv allows me to have multiple runtime environments for a single user, something not easily achievable by the other option. I get it now.